# Upload multi img to 1 post on Django ? How do that?

Tags: python, django

I want to upload multi img to 1 post on Django. I used ImageField in models.py. But it's just can upload 1 image to 1 post. How can i upload multi image to 1 post with Django or someways to solved that problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. Are you asking how to model one-to-many relationships in the ORM? Or about providing some specific UI in the user's browser?

Comment: Hi Chris, i mean, i want to create form with django and i can upload more than 1 img. i don't know how to do that. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the past answer.

I think this is the best way.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=400)

def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = instance.post.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    return "post_images/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)  


class Files(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    files = models.FileField(upload_to=get_image_filename, verbose_name='File')
```

I did not create a form for the files because we will write it manually in the template.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Images

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    body = forms.CharField(max_length=245, label="Item Description.")

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body', )
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post, Files

def post(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.FILES.getlist('files'))
        postForm = PostForm(request.POST)

        if postForm.is_valid():
            post_form = postForm.save(commit=False)
            post_form.save()
            if request.FILES.getlist('files'):
                for file in request.FILES.getlist('files'):
                    obj = Files(post=post_form, files=file)
                    obj.save()
            
            messages.success(request, "Yeeew, check it out on the home page!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            print(postForm.errors)
    else:
        postForm = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'postForm' : postForm})
```

index.html

```
<html>
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for hidden in postForm.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in postForm %}
        {{ field }} <br />
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</html>
```

We make such a field for the model of files that we do not form.

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple><br>
```

You can select multiple files and upload them by holding down CTRL or Shift.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are asking inline models,
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects