# How to upload multiple image with django rest api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, upload

I want to know how i can upload multiple image (list) in my views and get a Response like this :

```
{
 "id":1,
 "title":"text",
 "roms":2,
 "image":[
   "http:localhost:8000/media/images/houses/image1.png",
   "http:localhost:8000/media/images/houses/image2.png",
   "http:localhost:8000/media/images/houses/image3.png",
]
}
```

I have tried this way :

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class House(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rooms = models.IntegerField()
    images = models.FileField(upload_to="images/houses/")

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

**serializers.py***

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import House

class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   image = serializers.ListField(max_length=None,child=serializers.FileField)

   class Meta:
      model = House
      fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import House 
from .serializers import HouseSerializer

class HomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = House.objects.all()
   serialiezer_class = HouseSerializer
```

But it didn't work, i don't know how to write serializer and views to do this, any body help please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Upload multi img to 1 post on Django ? How do that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527402/upload-multi-img-to-1-post-on-django-how-do-that/63034749#63034749)

First of all you have to change your models. Then you need to add to this model by turning on the photos loaded with the for loop to your image model. I do not know exactly how to do this event with the rest api, but this is how it is done under normal conditions.